# How to get the value from the PK to FK using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

For example, I have this `DataContext`:

```
public class Adress
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Gatunamn { get; set; }
    public string Postnummer { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Postort { get; set; }

    public virtual Person PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

and want the PersonID from Person;

```
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Förnamn { get; set; }
    public string Efternamn { get; set; }
    public int Kontakt { get; set; }
```

by this:

```
var person = new Person()
             {
                Förnamn = förnamn,
                Efternamn = efternamn,
                Kontakt = kontakttyp
             };

var adress = new Adress()
             {                   
                PersonID = person.PersonID, <- want the ID from the new creating person..               
                Gatunamn = gatunamn,
                Postnummer = postnummer,
                Postort = postort
             };
```

But I can't because I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ProjectName.DataContext.Person'

(The `PersonID` is my FK)

Without the `PersonID = person.ID` the value in SQL Server is getting get to NULL.

I've also tried another way, but it also gives Null because I can't use the `PersonID` from the `Person` context class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigation properties

```
public class Adress
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Gatunamn { get; set; }
    public string Postnummer { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Postort { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var person = new Person()
        {
            Name = "Test name"
        };

        var adress = new Adress()
        {
            Postnummer = "Test",
            Person = person
        };


        Db.Adresses.Add(adress);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence was correct. You code isn't. The idea is to set `Person = person` so EF will save `person` first, then assign its new PK to `Address.PersonID` and save `Address`, all in one transaction.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I changed the code. this way it works all in one transaction